# PHP colon in property name

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable $entry which is set to:

> stdClass Object (
>       [im:name] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [label] => Amazing Breaker
>           )
>   etc.

How can I access the value "Amazing Breaker"?

I tried to define a constant:

```
define("IMNAME", 'im:name');
```

but using:

```
foreach ($json_output->feed->entry as $entry) {
if (isset($entry->IMNAME->label))
```

returns FALSE.

Problem seems to be the colon. For a key without colon the code would return TRUE.

Comment: Care to post the class definition that $entry is an object of?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the free-form syntax with curly braces for 'special' property names:

```
if (isset($entry->{'im:name'}->label))
```

Answer (score 7):

Curly braces!

```
echo $Node->{'im:name'}->label;
```

Basically, we're using a [Variable variable](https://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `IMNAME` with curly braces:

```
if (isset($entry->{IMNAME}->label))
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that variable names in PHP cannot contain a colon or double-colon. See https://php.net/manual/language.variables.basics.php for more information.

Does

```
$entry->{IMNAME}->label
```

work?