# Colon not allowed on PHP

Tags: php, syntax, properties, xml-namespaces

I want to navigate with this path:

```
$make = $entry->ad:vehicle->ad:make->resource:local-description;
```

But ":" are not allowed, how can i use ":" without any error?

Comment: Why is it so important to navigate with colon? Is this namespaced XML data? If so, you should be using namespacing correctly rather than trying to fudge it

Comment: If ad and resource are objects then you can keep using `->` operator

Comment: Yes alright. I'm reading a XML with child-attributes.

Comment: [Using PHP SimpleXML to get XML Namespace Elements](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP colon in property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211072/php-colon-in-property-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a qualifier like this:

```
$make = $entry->{"ad:vehicle"}->{"ad:make"}->{"resource:local-description"};
```